# Optimizing Postgres JSONB query with not null constraint

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've got a Postgres 9.4.4 database with 1.7 million records with the following information stored in a JSONB column called `data` in a table called `accounts`:

```
data: {
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2016-12-26T12:09:43.901Z",
  "UID": "2c5bb7fd-1a00-4988-8d92-ffaa52ebc20d",
  "data": {
    "country": "UK",
    "verified_at": "2017-01-01T23:49:10.217Z"
  }
}
```

The data format cannot be changed since this is legacy information.

I need to obtain all accounts where the country is `UK`, the `verified_at` value is not null and the `lastUpdatedTime` value is greater than some given value.

So far, I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "accounts"
WHERE (data @> '{ "data": { "country": "UK" } }')
AND (data->'data' ? 'verified_at')
AND ((data->'data' ->> 'verified_at') is not null)
AND (data ->>'lastUpdatedTime' > '2016-02-28T05:49:08.511846')
ORDER BY data ->>'lastUpdatedTime' LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

And the following indexes:

```
"accounts_idxgin" gin (data)
"accounts_idxgin_on_data" gin ((data -> 'data'::text))
```

I've managed to get the query time down to about 1000 to 4000ms

Here is the analyze from the query:

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on accounts  (cost=41.31..6934.50 rows=9 width=1719)
                               (actual time=7.273..1067.657 rows=23190 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((data -> 'data'::text) ? 'verified_at'::text)
   Filter: ((((data -> 'data'::text) ->> 'verified_at'::text) IS NOT NULL)
           AND ((data ->> 'lastUpdatedTime'::text) > '2016-02-01 05:49:08.511846'::text)
           AND (((data -> 'data'::text) ->> 'country'::text) = 'UK'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 4
   Heap Blocks: exact=16039
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on accounts_idxgin_on_data  (cost=0.00..41.30 rows=1773 width=0)
       (actual time=4.618..4.618 rows=23194 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((data -> 'data'::text) ? 'verified_at'::text)
 Planning time: 0.448 ms
 Execution time: 1069.344 ms
(9 rows)
```

I have the following questions

1. Is there anything I can do to further speed up this query?
2. What is the correct way to speed up a `field is not null` query with JSONB? I ended up using the existence operator with `(data->'data' ? 'verified_at')` to filter out a large number of non-matching records, because much of my data doesn't have `verified_at` as a top level key.   This increased the speed of the query, but I'm wondering if there's a general approach to optimizing this type of query.
3. In order to use the existence operator with `(data->'data' ? 'verified_at')`, I needed to add another index on `((data -> 'data'::text))`. I already had an index on `gin (data)`, but the existence operator didn't use this.  Why is that? I thought the existence and containment operators would use this index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around a bit more, I've managed to reduce my query time from around 1000ms to 350ms by creating the following partial index:

```
 CREATE INDEX index_accounts_partial_on_verified_at
 ON accounts ((data->'data'->'verified_at'))
 WHERE (data->'data'->>'verified_at') IS NOT NULL
 AND (data->'data' ? 'verified_at')
 AND (data->'data'->>'country' = 'UK');
```

I was able to hardcode some of the values in this index, such as `country=UK` because I only need to consider `UK` accounts for this query.  I was also able to remove the index on `((data->'data'))` which was 258MB, and replace it with the partial index which is only 1360 kB!

For anyone interested, I found the details for building a partial JSONB index from [here](https://blog.heapanalytics.com/speeding-up-postgresql-queries-with-partial-indexes/.)

Answer (score 5):

3: Not really. This case is [explicitly mentioned in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING).
   When you have an index on the column `data`, it is only used, when you query your table, like `data @> '...'` or `data ? '...'`. When you have an index on the expression `(data -> 'data')`, these queries can take advantage of it: `(data -> 'data') @> '...'` or `(data -> 'data') ? '...'`.

2: usual `jsonb` indexes won't help during a `(jsonb_col -> '<key>') is [not] null` query at all. And unfortunately, you cannot use `jsonb_col @> '{"<key>":null}'` either, because the JSON object might lack the key entirely. Also reverse use of the index (for `is not null`) is not possible at all. But there may be a trick...

1: Not much. There may be some improvements, but don't expect huge performance advantages. So here them go:

You can use the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class instead of the (default) `jsonb_ops`. This should mean a little improvement in performance, but they cannot use the existence operator (`?`). But we won't need it anyway.

You have a single, index-unfriendly, `boolean` typed expression, which slows you down. Thankfully you can use a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) here if you only interested in `true` values.

So, your index should look something like this:

```
create index accounts_idxgin_on_data
  on accounts using gin ((data -> 'data') jsonb_path_ops)
  where (data -> 'data' ->> 'verified_at') is not null;
```

With this index, you can use the following query:

```
select   *
from     accounts
where    (data -> 'data') @> '{"country":"UK"}'
and      (data -> 'data' ->> 'verified_at') is not null
and      (data ->> 'lastUpdatedTime') > '2016-02-28T05:49:08.511Z'
order by data ->>'lastUpdatedTime';
```

**Note**: for proper `timestamp` comparisons, you should use `(data ->> 'lastUpdatedTime')::timestamptz > '2016-02-28T05:49:08.511Z'`.

http://rextester.com/QWUW41874

Comment: Thanks for the response pozs.  I've tried your index and query and it gives me an execution time of around 1000ms, and if I perform a `count(*)`, I get about the same result.  From the partial index that I came up with in my answer, I was able to get the query time to about 600ms and a `count(*)` to 450ms, so I'm going to stick with my index and query.  In regards to your answer for question 3)  the docs didn't make sense to me at the time, but now I understand it, thanks for the clarification.  Your answer to 2) verifies my suspicions. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the path access operator for faster access to lower-level objects:

```
SELECT * FROM "accounts"
WHERE data #>> '{data, country}' = 'UK'
  AND data #>> '{data, verified_at}' IS NOT NULL
  AND data ->> 'lastUpdatedTime' > '2016-02-28T05:49:08.511846'
ORDER BY data ->> 'lastUpdatedTime' LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

The index only works on the top-level key. So, with an index on column `data` queries like `data @> [[key]]` are supported. However, for a query on `data -> 'data' ? 'verified_at'` you need an index on `data->'data'`.

Two more points:

- I don't think it is necessary to test for the presence of `verified_at`. If it is not there it simply comes out as NULL so it gets caught by the same test.
- Comparing string representations of `timestamp` values may work if the JSON value is properly and consistently formatted. Cast to `timestamp` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrick. I've tried your query suggestion, but the path access operator didn't make any difference, and removing the existence operator condition `(data->'data' ? 'verified_at')` resulted in a much slower query because the `((data -> 'data'))` index wasn't used, so the execution time increased to 15912.736 ms.